# Is it secure to use a POST email and password over HTTPS to authenticate the users of an internal API?

Tags: api, security, authentication, https

I came on board an existing project and one of my tasks is to make sure that the application is secure. It's a desktop application and it makes a lot of calls to an internal API. When a user needs to be authenticated on one of these internal API calls they are currently passing a POST email and password over HTTPS.

Is this secure? If not, what's the easiest way to upgrade it so that it is secure?

Comment: Secure against what?

Comment: Attackers stealing logins or successfully attacking our application in other ways due to us authenticating with a POST email/password over HTTPS.

Comment: Compared to what? Why wouldn't it be secure?

Comment: I am asking because I don't know if it's secure. I guess compared to some sort of token based authentication, or some other setup I am unaware of. Are you saying it is secure?

Answer (score 1):

Application security is not a black and white thing. It depends on what threats you have to worry about.

Username/password authentication is simple to implement, but not the best way to protect an API. For one thing, the client application has to keep the clear text password in memory to send it along with each request.

The server side has to validate the password against some store. Secure password storage is really hard.

If you're on an Active Directory domain, [Integrated Windows Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication) may be a better option. It's transparent to both client and server, but it only works within the domain.

If it also needs to work outside the intranet, token based security (like [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/)) is an option, but this requires more changes to both client and service.

Comment: What's the simplest way to introduce a token?

Comment: The easiest way is to use a out-of-the-box authorization server and standard library. This Azure AD sample seems like what you're trying to do: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop